# open folder from program started as SYSTEM in C#

Tags: c#

A service launches an exe program successfully using this code:

```
using (Process myProcess = new Process()) {

      myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = processFolderPath;
      myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "PROCESS_1.exe";
      myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
      myProcess.Start();
   }
```

From `PROCESS_1`, I'd like to open a folder:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Users\mainuser\Documents\folder_to_open");
```

This works if the `PROCESS_1` is started normally by double clicking the exe or as admin. But it fails to open a folder, if `PROCESS_1` is started from service and is running as `SYSTEM`.

Is it possible to open a folder in explorer if the process trying to open a folder is run as SYSTEM from a Service?

Comment: A service does not by default have access to the user's session. See duplicate for a possible work-around. Keeping in mind that in general, it's a really poor practice to have a service doing any sort of GUI presentation at all. You should prefer a program a user explicitly runs for managing that sort of thing.

Comment: Services are (for good reasons) typically not allowed to interact with the desktop. Same probably applies to processes started by a service. Especially opening new windows from the service seems a bad idea because that will interfere with the users current work. And what happens, if there is no user logged on, but the service is of course still running?